# MySQL TIME comparisons

Tags: mysql, time, comparison, hour

I need to store a TV guide in MYSQL and I was thinking something like this:

```
channel_id         day      start_time  end_time

AMC Breaking Bad:) Monday   19:00:00    20:30:00

Other Program      Saturday 09:30:00    12:30:00
```

`end_time` and `start_time` are `TIME` fields and store **HOURS**.

My problem and questions is:

**How can I get from MYSQL what programs are watching NOW()?** I don't know how to compare the hours. I done some test, but i get nothing.

Hope you understand my English!
Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are asking how I can get a list of programs that are on right now where NOW is greater than or equal to the start_time and less than the end_time. With those assumptions here is the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tv_guide
WHERE CURTIME() BETWEEN start_time AND end_time;
```

EDIT: As @Corbin notes, you will need to check the day.

Comment: HI again, I've one more question! How can a I subtract to CURRENT_TIME() function a few hours, to get the programs that are coming soon?

Comment: @mauriblint, the DATE_SUB function should work: WHERE DATE_SUB(CURTIME(), INTERVAL 2 HOURS) BETWEEN start_time AND end_time. That would give you 2 hours before the current time or DATE_ADD to get a few hours after the current time: WHERE DATE_ADD(CURTIME(), INTERVAL 2 HOURS) BETWEEN start_time AND end_time

Comment: I think there will be a problem if start_time=23:00:00 and end_time=01:00:00. Now if curtime is 23:30:00 you will not get the correct result. I also implemented using BETWEEN but no facing a problem in the situation I mentioned and trying to find a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM shows WHERE CURRENT_TIME() BETWEEN start_time AND end_time;
```

You'll probably also want to check the day as well, but that's just another where clause (`AND day = 'Friday'`).

Comment: HI again, I've one more question! How can a I subtract to CURRENT_TIME() function a few hours, to get the programs that are coming soon?